# how to change the data in to different language which is coming from server?

Tags: android, parsing, multilingual

I want to provide option to the user for select or choose language, actually data stored on server is in English language .

when user choose any other language ,the whole application or app data will be change in to that selected language.

I have already visited so many links for do this task .they provide solution to make individual string for all type of data and put it in to values folder .

the main thing is that I want to display data in to different language which is coming throw parsing from the server!

so any one has idea or logic about how to convert that data run time programmatically in android ,then plz comment it...

any suggestion will be acceptable !! thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet will be to look for a translation API you can call when requesting data.

Answer (score 0):

Feed the response data to the [Translation API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) by Google or the Microsoft equivalent [Bing Translator](https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/). For both you will need a unique API key.

Comment: can u send me the link , which shows how to integrate this API s ??

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have to just store all languages data into backend server with some language id. Based on this language id you can dynamically display different language data in your app.

Comment: Thanks @kumarpal , I did the same.

Comment: @Radhey Can you please explain it clearly how you implemented it? It would be of great help. We are trying to do the same thing, but not able to understand how exactly the above solution needs to be implemented.

Comment: @MohitKhaitan, you need to set predefined language tag let say for english (TAG_EN) , franch (TAG_FR) etc..both side, backend server side and mobile side locally. while api calls you need to pass this language tag and accordingly  your server sends data form DB with associated matching language tag inside response.